# Cannot execute PostgreSQL function with Jooq

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

Java 1.8, Jooq 3.10.3, Postgres 10.1

I created Postgres function which get table parameter. After JOOQ generate code I tried to call function from Java code but got strange exception.

Postgres part:

```sql
CREATE TABLE testtab
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  txt character varying,
  CONSTRAINT testtab_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.testfunc(val testtab)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS //

begin
  insert into testtab select  * from val;
end;

//;
```

Java Part (TesttabRecord and Testfunc generated by Jooq codegen):

```java
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password)) {
    DSLContext cxt = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
    TesttabRecord r = new TesttabRecord(1, "test");
    Testfunc f = new Testfunc();
    f.setVal(r);

    f.execute(cxt.configuration());
}
```

Get exception:

> Jan 19, 2018 10:17:26 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger warn WARNING: Not
>   supported by dialect : Type class test.db.tables.records.TesttabRecord
>   is not supported in dialect POSTGRES
>   org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class
>   test.db.tables.records.TesttabRecord is not supported in dialect
>   POSTGRES  at org.jooq_3.10.3.POSTGRES.debug(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:855)
>     at
>   org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:799)
>     at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding.toSQLCast(DefaultBinding.java:358)
>     at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding.sql(DefaultBinding.java:290)    at
>   org.jooq.impl.Val.accept(Val.java:80)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:415)
>     at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit0(AbstractContext.java:423)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:184)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.Tools.renderAndBind(Tools.java:1945)    at
>   org.jooq.impl.SQLImpl.accept(SQLImpl.java:66)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:415)
>     at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit0(AbstractContext.java:423)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:184)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.SQLField.accept(SQLField.java:65)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:415)
>     at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit0(AbstractContext.java:423)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:184)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.QueryPartList.accept(QueryPartList.java:101)    at
>   org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:415)
>     at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit0(AbstractContext.java:423)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:184)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.Function.toSQLArguments1(Function.java:445)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.Function.toSQLArguments0(Function.java:427)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.Function.toSQLArguments(Function.java:422)  at
>   org.jooq.impl.Function.accept(Function.java:226)  at
>   org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:415)
>     at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit0(AbstractContext.java:423)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:184)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractRoutine$RoutineField.accept(AbstractRoutine.java:1635)
>     at
>   org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:415)
>     at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit0(AbstractContext.java:423)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:184)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.Tools.renderAndBind(Tools.java:1945)    at
>   org.jooq.impl.SQLImpl.accept(SQLImpl.java:66)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:415)
>     at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit0(AbstractContext.java:423)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:184)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.SQLTable.accept(SQLTable.java:82)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:415)
>     at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit0(AbstractContext.java:394)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:184)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.QueryPartList.accept(QueryPartList.java:101)    at
>   org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:415)
>     at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit0(AbstractContext.java:423)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:184)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.toSQLReference0(SelectQueryImpl.java:1190)
>     at
>   org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.toSQLReference0(SelectQueryImpl.java:978)
>     at
>   org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.toSQLReferenceLimitDefault(SelectQueryImpl.java:771)
>     at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.accept(SelectQueryImpl.java:604)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:415)
>     at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit0(AbstractContext.java:423)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:184)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.getSQL0(AbstractQuery.java:498)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:306)   at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:317)
>     at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:2597)     at
>   org.jooq.impl.AbstractRoutine.executeSelectFromPOSTGRES(AbstractRoutine.java:433)
>     at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRoutine.execute(AbstractRoutine.java:335)
>     at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRoutine.execute(AbstractRoutine.java:317)

What's wrong with code above? I'll appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Any chance to edit your question to make it more human readable and share a little info with it? First text, problem-statement and thereafter start posting code.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, isn't it? The jooq doesn't allow to use PostgreSQL JDBC for this kind of task.

Comment: @ZF007 You're right. My 'question' is confusing. Now fixed.

Comment: @KarlRichter I couldn't find any info about such limitations so I posted question here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug / missing feature: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7174

There's currently (jOOQ 3.10) no good workaround for it, short of overloading the function and passing either:

- A composite type that looks like the table type (`CREATE TYPE`)
- Individual arguments per table column

#### On the syntax of your function:

There's a minor glitch in your function as well:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.testfunc(val testtab)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS //
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO testtab VALUES (val.*); -- You cannot use val in FROM
END;
//;
```

Answer (score 0):

There shoud be `Routines` class generated, which should include your routine. There you will find which arguments it takes.